# custom coding style setting of clang-format

Tags: clang-format

I am trying to figure out how to set the coding style for my code up with clang-format. What I want to do is as follows:

1. break before and after the inheritance symbol `:`
2. inheritance symbol `:` has no indentation
3. inheritance list breaks after comma and aligned
4. access modifier has no indentation
5. doxygen single line comment has additional indentation relative to the C++ single line indentation

**Desired coding style example:**

```
class A
:
    public B,
    public C
{
public:

    // some comment
        //- doxygen comment
        ...
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've being experimenting with clang-format quite a lot, and while it has a very rich set of [options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), it is customizable only to some extent (being limited by the available set of options), and achieving the exact desired customization is sometimes not possible, especially if it is non-standard or "exotic".

Specifically, I couldn't find options for:

- breaking *after* the inheritance symbol
- inheritance list break after the comma
- additional indentation for doxygen comments.

For breaking *before* the inheritance comma, set the option `BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true` in your `.clang-format` file.

For setting no indentation for the access modifier, set `AccessModifierOffset: <-N>`, where `N` is the indent width, since access modifiers default indentation is by one level. For example:

```
IndentWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: -4
```